# Spring Boot ignoring Jackson Annotations in Rest Controller

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson

So I have an abstract root class `Model` which has various subclasses. Model is annotated with the following:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
        property = "model")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = LowerBoundThresholdModel.class, name = "LowerBoundThresholdAnomalyDetector"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = UpperBoundThresholdModel.class, name = "UpperBoundThresholdAnomalyDetector"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MovingAverageLowerBoundThresholdModel.class, name = "MovingAverageLowerBoundThresholdAnomalyDetector"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MovingAverageUpperBoundThresholdModel.class, name = "MovingAverageUpperBoundThresholdAnomalyDetector"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = WindowedUpperBoundThresholdModel.class, name = "WindowedLowerBoundThresholdAnomalyDetector"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = WindowedUpperBoundThresholdModel.class, name = "WindowedUpperBoundThresholdAnomalyDetector")
})
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Data
public abstract class Model {
```

I have a controller annotated with `@RestController` and a method like this:

```
@GetMapping("/api/v1/models")
public ResponseEntity<Iterable<Model>> getAllModels() {
    try {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(modelService.getAll());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(500).build();
    }
}
```

I have one test which correctly serializes the Models:

```
public class JacksonTest extends AbstractApplicationTest {

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Test
    public void shouldSerialiseEvent() throws JsonProcessingException {
        LowerBoundThresholdModel lowerBoundThresholdModel = new LowerBoundThresholdModel();
        lowerBoundThresholdModel.setThreshold(1.0);

        String s = mapper.writeValueAsString(lowerBoundThresholdModel);
        assertThat(s).contains("model").contains("LowerBoundThresholdAnomalyDetector");
    }
}
```

However when I test the actual RestController it doesn't seem to use the Jackson annotations and doesn't include the class information in the `model` field as configured:

```
@Test
public void shouldReturnListOfExistingModels() throws Exception {
    LowerBoundThresholdModel lowerBoundThresholdModel = new LowerBoundThresholdModel();
    lowerBoundThresholdModel.setThreshold(1.0);
    lowerBoundThresholdModelRepository.save(lowerBoundThresholdModel);
    windowedLowerBoundThresholdModelRepository.save(windowedLowerBoundThresholdModel);

    mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/models"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$[0].model", is("LowerBoundThresholdModel")))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$[0].threshold", is(lowerBoundThresholdModel.getThreshold())))
}
```

but this test fails with `no such JSON path $[0].model`

How can I make the controller use the same object mapper so that my JSON output from the controllers is correct?

EDIT: if I remove the line `andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$[0].model", is("LowerBoundThresholdModel")))` it passes so its not to do with `Iterable` not being converted to an indexed array

Comment: Please check if it works when changing `Iterable<Model>`to `List<Model>`.

Comment: Can you make this an answer because it works as you suggest :)

Comment: Hi, did you ever solve this? I tried with ResponseEntity and without but I could not get it to work

Answer (score 0):

`Iterator` does not allow indexed access to a list of items. It just returns the next element. So calling `$[0]` fails.

By widening the Interface to `List` it works as expected.

```
@GetMapping("/api/v1/models")
public ResponseEntity<List<Model>> getAllModels() {
    try {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(modelService.getAll());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(500).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok interestingly it sort of still works with `Iterable` it just doesn't honor the Jackson annotations. I can still access the JSON rendered with indexes even with it being `Iterable` its just the `model` field which wasn't being populated